# how to create multiple form field based on a list (with multiple items) in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I would like to create a multiple form field in SharePoint 2010.
Something similar to DataSheet View.

I have created a multiple form in SharePoint Designer but its on Edit Mode.
Instead of in Edit Mode I want a new form.

So users can just type into the textboxes with multiple entries etc and just hit save
this will be a batch save.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Visual Web Part with GridView/Repeater ?

Comment: Thanks Arsalan sure VS studio would be ideal but didn't want to go that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own custom html form and used some jQuery to allow users to insert a new row then use the Lists.asmx web service to batch add the new items. It wasn't difficult to do and using libraries l ike SPServices makes it easy to wrap all the items into a batch add operation.

Depending on the complexity of your form this may not work, but for my need it was a small form but users might need to add 3, 4, 5+ items at a time easily.

Comment: I was already thinking of using SPServices but i taught let me give sharepoint designer a try first but i couldn't have a new formwith mutiple entries.
Do you have the solution online? Thanks

Comment: No, nothing online. I had my form laid out horizontally, then had some jQuery clone the row on a button/image click and remove the values from the cloned row. Then using jQuery on save click, I iterated over all the rows building up a batch command for a SPServices call.

Comment: Taught of this exact solution :) will see how I go